# SELECT SQL data filtered by Week

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

Hi i'm trying to make a filter for my logs by day, week, month and year.
However i'm lost in trying to filter by week.

```
ID   User   Date         Time 
------------------------------
0   user1   01/25/2018   11:00    
1   user1   01/26/2018   14:00   
2   user2   01/26/2018   08:00    
3   user3   01/11/2018   01:00    
4   user2   01/22/2018   02:00    
5   user3   01/16/2018   14:00
```

then if i filter it by week 4 of january so it should show up like this

```
ID   User  Date       Time
---------------------------
0    user1 01/25/2018 11:00    
1    user1 01/26/2018 14:00    
2    user2 01/26/2018 08:00    
4    user2 01/22/2018 02:00
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server  ?????

Comment: oh i forgot, its mysql

Comment: like if i choose the date of 01/25/2018 then it will filter the logs from that week of the chosen date.

Comment: i have posted  and answer  ...hope is usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql you can select  use week()

```
  select * from my_table 
  where week(date) =4
```

or you can use yeraweek()

```
  select * from my_table 
  where week(date) =201804
```

or as in your comment

```
select * from my_table 
where week(date) = week('2018-01-25')
```

Comment: @samir  in mysql 2018-08-22  is august  22 so the week should 33  and weeek(date) = 4 is only the 4th week of the year is not the 4week of month

Comment: If you need  the 4th week of the month you must convert as  `FLOOR((DayOfMonth(date)-1)/7)+1`

Comment: thanks, how about for sql-server, will it be the same?